# How do you estimate glucose and sucrose levels of a food product?

Tags: nutrition, sugar, supplement, glucose

Is it possible to estimate approximately what the percentage of glucose and the percentage of sucrose is in a food product, simply by looking at the ingredients and nutritional information?

Answer (score -2):

I check the carbs and it usually says  40 grams and "amount that's sugar: 12 grams". Then you know the carbs and how much is from sugar per gram.

Even 8-9 grams of sugar per 100grams is super much, that's like 10% for only that bottle/food. Carbs are ok at long it's fiber and good carbs with a low sugar rate.

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all.